# How to solve the "Inner matrix dimensions must agree." in MATLAB but I do have made the dimensions the same

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions

I have been using MATLAB to finish some work but I have encountered some problem.
MATLAB tells me that:

```
  Error using  * 
  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

  Error in iterationHn (line 29)
  revisedFup=trVnew*Foldup*Vnew;
```

But I do have made sure that trVnew,Foldup,Vnew are both 8x8 double matrix.
There is no dimension problem I think.
So How can solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: well, if MATLAB retrieves that error, perhaps it's not really true that the two matrix are 8-by-8 in dimension.

Comment: `size(trVnew)` vs `size(Foldup)` vs `size(Vnew)` ???

Comment: Yes.If you further check the software it will be different when the loop grow bigger.

Comment: -1: I don't agree with the initial up-vote. This is a 'debug' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error only happens if you have an error in your dimensions. Try placing a breakpoint on line 29 and inspect the dimensions at that point. You may have accidentally overwritten one of the matrices (e.g. changed its dimensions).

Comment: Yep!Thanks for your adveice!

Comment: I use breakpoint to study the effect of the code and I do make some mistakes when the n grows big.

Comment: Those kinds of errors are great to discover flaws in your implementation. In a way, you are lucky to get them since they are very much in-your-face (in contrast to silent fails which can take ages to debug).